transferring money from Philippines to US
I recently inherited real property from my mom's passing in the Philippines along side with my siblings. We are intending to sell the property, pay taxes and split among us. I'm still holding Philippino citizenship but permanently resident (green card holder) in the US. What would be best approach to bring my portion of the proceed to the US?
Thank you!

Does this answer your question? Transferring money from the Philippines to the USA?

no, because on other article, he is US citizen vs I'm still Philippo citizen with a green card.

That doesn't matter, the difference between green card and citizens is voting rights and ability to reside elsewhere, neither is relevant to your question

Is there anything special about this question? Would an ordinary international wire work?

Hi Francis. I sold a condo in Manila in Nov 2022 and transferred the money using BCRemit. My transfer was to GBP in the UK but they may offer services to transfer to the US and Im sure there are similar companies but obviously be careful to make sure theyre legit. Per littleadv's answer to the question that he linked, I had to declare and pay capital gains tax in the UK.

There are numerous services that will transfer money between countries for a modest fee. I'm a US citizen living in the Philippines. I regularly move money in the opposite direction, from the US to the Philippines. When I was first planning to move here I did some research into these services, and at the time I concluded that the best options were Wise and Remitly. I've never tried to move money from the Philippines to the US, but I think either would do that. For relatively small amounts, like a few hundred to a few thousand US dollars, the fee is about 1%. For bigger amounts the percentage fee is less.
You can also do a SWIFT and wire transfers are also possible, but MUCH more expensive.
As I say, I've only moved money from the US to the Philippines. If anyone on here has experience going the other way, I'll gladly yield.
